# Kubernetes use Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-blob-storage

How do I create a secret to access Azure Blob storage if I am using SAS token authentication mode?

```
{
    "account_name": "<value>",
    "container_name": "<value>",
    "container_uri": "<value>",
    "region": "<value>",
    "sas_token": "<value>"
}
```

I cannot find any information about this on the docs

Comment: Are you looking at the following docs. These docs should have fair amount of info on how to use SAS tokens. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#get-started-with-sas

Answer (score 1):

You create a SAS from the protal or via az cli:

```bash
AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP="my-rg"
AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT="my-sa"

export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="$(az storage account show-connection-string \
  --name "$AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" \
  --resource-group "$AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP" \
  -o tsv)"

AZURE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN="$(az storage account generate-sas \
  --services b \
  --resource-types co \
  --permissions dlpruwac \
  --expiry "$(date -d '+7 days' '+%FT%H:%MZ')" \
  -o tsv)"
```

> **Note** the --services, --resource-types and --permissions flags. In the above example the token was generated for blob storage, on container & objects within the container with the permissions: delete, list, process, read, update, write, add & create.

```
--permissions    [Required] :     The permissions the SAS grants. Allowed values: (a)dd (c)reate
                                  (d)elete (f)ilter_by_tags (i)set_immutability_policy (l)ist
                                  (p)rocess (r)ead (t)ag (u)pdate (w)rite (x)delete_previous_version
                                  (y)permanent_delete. Can be combined.
--resource-types [Required] :     The resource types the SAS is applicable for. Allowed values:
                                  (s)ervice (c)ontainer (o)bject. Can be combined.
--services       [Required] :     The storage services the SAS is applicable for. Allowed values:
                                  (b)lob (f)ile (q)ueue (t)able. Can be combined.
```

See more info with `az storage account generate-sas --help`.

Once you have the token you can create the secret (Note, you need the variables from the previous code snippet).

```bash
AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONTAINER="<my-container>"

jq -n \
    --arg account_name "$AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" \
    --arg container_name "$AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONTAINER" \
    --arg container_uri "$(az storage account show -n "$AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" -g "$AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP" --query primaryEndpoints.blob -o tsv)$AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONTAINER" \
    --arg region "$(az storage account show -n "$AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" -g "$AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP" --query primaryLocation -o tsv)" \
    --arg sas_token "$AZURE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN" '{
    "account_name": $account_name,
    "container_name": $container_name,
    "container_uri": $container_uri,
    "region": $region,
    "sas_token": $sas_token
    }' |
    kubectl create secret generic storage-account --from-file=data.json=/dev/stdin
```

You can change the name of the secret and the file name within the secret by modifying the kubectl command.

You also need to check if you should append the container name to the container uri yourself or if the library using this data is doing it. Above, I have added the container name, you may want to remove it from the uri.

If you dont need to append the container name to the uri, you could simplify the json generation like this below. Using a query to get multiple fields from az cli.

```bash
AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONTAINER="<my-container>"

az storage account show -n $AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT -g $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --query '{account_name:name,container_uri:primaryEndpoints.blob,region:primaryLocation}' |
    jq --arg sas_token "$AZURE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN" --arg container_name "$AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONTAINER" \
        '. + { "sas_token": $sas_token, "container_name": $container_name}' |
    kubectl create secret generic storage-account --from-file=data.json=/dev/stdin
```

Comment: SAS tokens are supposed to be ephemeral, that's the whole point. You should store the storage account key as secret and create SAS on demand in code.

Comment: @evilSnobu, the account key on the other hand is not meant to be epehemeral. I would not hand this out to an application. Why do you even need an SAS token if you have the account key, anyway?  If you need to rotate the SAS token in the secret, you should implement a different mechanism. Perhaps user delegation would be the clean way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-cli#create-a-user-delegation-sas-for-a-container.

Comment: Let's up the bar and not expose any secrets to the app. They could mount the Blob CSI driver and expose that to the app - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-blob-csi?tabs=NFS